# What is the difference between ways to point in arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Assume that I define x as array like this:   `int x[30]={2,4,8,9,6,3,5,4,7,8,9,6,3,2,}` and `A` as a pointer to an `int` like this:  `int *A`.

Now I want to know what the difference is between these:

1. `int *A=x[5]`
2. `int *A ; A=&x[5]`
3. `int *A=x+5`
4. `int *A ; *A=x+5`
5. `int *A ; A=*(x+5)`

Why do number 1, 4 and 5 give an error?

Number 4 gives an error although number 3 doesn't. Why are these not equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In number 1, you're creating a variable `A` which is a pointer to an `int`, and `x[5]` is an `int`, not a pointer. So you're giving a pointer an `int` value, which produces an error.

In number 2, you create a pointer to an `int` and then make it point to the variable `x[5]`, since `&x[5]` is the address of `x[5]`. That will compile just fine and the way you wrote it won't produce any error, however creating a pointer without any initial value is not recommended. When you create `A` without initializing it, it will take the value that was already in the memory which can be any value. Therefore, if you use the variable `A` before giving it an error, your program will crash. Instead, it's recommended to do:

```
int *A = NULL;
A = &x[5];
```

or simply:

```
int *A= &x[5];
```

In number 3, you're creating a pointer to an `int` and you're assigning it the value `x + 5`. This is OK since `x` is in fact a pointer to `x[0]` (`x` and `&x[0]` do exactly the same thing). So `x + 5` is a pointer to the value that is 5 memory spaces after `x[0]`, which is `x[5]`. In fact, when the compiler sees `x[5]`, it converts it to `*(x + 5)`.

In number 4, `A` is a pointer to an `int`, so `*A` is the value which `A` is pointing to, which is an `int`. In you're code, `*A = x + 5` is wrong for two reasons: For the first reason, the code won't compile since `x + 5` is a pointer and `*A` is an `int`, so you're assigning a pointer value to an `int`, which isn't valid. But there is another error in there. Imaging it compiled for some reason. Then, at runtime, what it does, is that it takes the memory space that `A` is pointing to and gives it the value `x + 5`. The problem is that `A` isn't initialized so it's very likely that `A` points to a variable used by another program. To prevent this from doing any damage, your OS will make the program crash. If you're "lucky", `A` will point to a variable in your program so it will assign a new value to a variable in your program without you knowing which variable it is, so your program will continue running but won't work correctly.

In number 5, `A` is a pointer to an `int` and you're assigning it the value `*(x + 5)`. As I explained earlier, `*(x + 5)` is exactly the same thing as `x[5]`, which is an `int`. So you're assigning an `int` value to a pointer, which is not valid. Note that if for some reason you want to assign an `int` value to a pointer, you could do `A = (int*)(*(x + 5))`, which would compile properly (but the program would probably crash at runtime). Then `A` would be a pointer pointing to the memory space `3`. In the same way, you can also do `x[5] = (int)A`, which stores the address of the variable that `A` is pointing to as an `int` in `x[5]`. However, I've never seen any situation where these kinds of things would be useful in practice.

Comment: Re: `...since x is in fact a pointer to x[0]...`. You need to be careful when explaining arrays and pointers. `x` is not a pointer, it's an array. But when it appears in an expression (other than argument of `sizeof`; in our case `x + 5` is the expression), it gets converted to a pointer to the first element of the array. And then we deal with pointer arithmetic. Adding 5 to a pointer advances the pointer by 5 elements, so `x + 5` ends up pointing to element 5 of array `x`.